# Are all these groups CAT(0) groups?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, gr.group-theory

Given a geodesic metric space $X$ together with a choice of midpoints
$m:X\times X\rightarrow X$ (i.e. $d(m(x,y),x)=d(m(x,y),y)=d(x,y)/2$).
Assume furthermore, that the following nonpositive curvature condition is satisfied:

$d(m(x,y),m(x,z))\le \frac{d(y,z)}{2}$ for all $x,y,z\in X$ .
This is just a special case of the CAT(0) inequality for the "triangle" $x,y,z$.
Lets call such a space a M-space.

Such a space needn't be [CAT(0)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT(k)_space), as the example $(\mathbb{R}^n,d^1)$ shows, where $d^1$ is the $l^1$ metric. The choice of midpoints is given by $m(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{2}$. It also needn't be unique geodesic.

But this space can be equipped with another metric, that makes it a CAT(0) space.

So my question is: Is every group, that acts properly, isometrically and cocompactly on a M-space already a CAT(0)-group?

Comment: You might find this paper and references therein helpful:
http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0704.3749

See also:
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2106770
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2197811

Comment: Tiny nitpick: I would call this a 'non-positive curvature' condition, rather than a  'negative curvature' condition.

Comment: Ian, median spaces are not the same as M-spaces. Otherwise the answer would be positive (median spaces admitting co-compact proper isometric actions should be closely related to CAT(0)-cubical complexes). I think that an M-space does not necessarily have quadratic "isoperimetric" function, hence the answer should be in fact negative. 

Comment: The first link in [Ian's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37968/are-all-these-groups-cat0-groups#comment88599_37968) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3749